# IF applied to FORECAST functions

Tags: excel, forecasting

I'm trying to create a forecast formula in excel using the if (like a sumif, for instance) but I'm not being able to find anything on Google that describes how it can be done.

My idea is not that complex, but excel does not support directly the calculation. I'm trying to do something similar to the following:

```
=sumif($A:$A;Z1;$B:$B)
```

But instead the sumif, I would like to apply any FORECAST formula, such as FORECAST.ETS, FORECAST.LINEAR, etc..

Someone imagines how to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Stax, I understand what is required by the FORECAST function. My doubt is if is possible to do some IF on the FORECAST functions, like we have on the sumif. I'm still going to provide the target date, values, etc., but I would like to apply the FORECAST in a range only on the cells that meet the IF requirements, like we have in the SUMIF for the SUM function.

Comment: "only on the cells that meet the IF requirements,.." then (imho), extract the new list > feed to `forecast` should work.

Comment: p._phidot_, this exactly what I want to avoid - I wanna make something automatic, not something that I need always to extract the data to be able to apply the calculation.

Comment: then you need a to generate a new table from the matched IF , then only apply the FORECAST function. In new excel vesion you may use `FILTER()` for this